# Tomcat Environment Variables Setup (9.0.45)

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I have setup and envrionment variables in my Tomcat installation. I have added this to my catalina.bat and startup.bat, right after setlocal line:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-DAPP_ROOT_DIR=C:\opt\app
```

But when I debug in Eclipse the line:

```
setStaticDirName(System.getProperty(envVarName));
```

where `envVarName` is set to `APP_ROOT_DIR` like this in the class:

```
private static final String envVarName = "APP_ROOT_DIR";
```

It throws a NullPointerException. Am i doing something wrong here. I am pretty sure this is how we set up environment variables and use it in code.

Comment: Are you using the `startup.bat/catalina.bat` scripts to start Tomcat or you start it in a different way (e.g. IDE, procrun, etc.)?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes i am using the script to start the Tomcat.

Comment: You can add a `logEnv="true"` attribute to the `VersionLoggerListener` in `server.xml` to print all environment variables on server startup.